# buy till you die - Discounted cash flow - NBD/GAMMA

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, poisson-distribution, data-mining, customer-lifetime-value

I was learning about BYTD in an online tutorial [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-is-your-customers-worth-over-their-lifetime-dfae277fd166)

I understand that it is used

a) to predict the number of purchases that will be made by the customer.

b) Lifetime value of the cuatomer over a defined period.

I see that the authors use a term called "Discounted cash flow" and assign 0.01% as monthly discount.

However, I don't unserstand this.

Can someone help me understand what is the use of DCF and why should we use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Future cash reflects the belief that it's more valuable to have a dollar today than a dollar tomorrow. At a very high level of abstraction, if you have a dollar today, you have the option to either spend it or keep it. Keeping the dollar naturally implies that you have the dollar tomorrow, so the case of having a dollar today also includes the outcome "have a dollar tomorrow" among your options.

Another way to look at it is that you could die before tomorrow, and in that case, you'd never realize the value of getting a dollar tomorrow.